# Boolean a face and vertices in a Geometry Nodes generated mesh

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

Situation:

[image]

I would like delete the face of the cube in the back and the overlapping vertices, when the Z-value of the moving part and the cube are equal. I used this node tree (index 9 is the top face of the cube):

[image]

However, deleting the face and vertices will create a black line (edge) between vertices 16 and 24 (see end of GIF). I know this has to do with the `merge by distance` node, which I use to delete the overlapping vertices. Later in the tree I use a subdivision surface and then the problems arise (see figure below), so I want to get rid of this generated edge. How do I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The `Merge by Distance` node must be in front of the `Delete Geometry` node.